# auto-saving-image-from-camera-capture-in-one-click-in-c-net.The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#

```
private void BtnChupxevao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IDataObject data;
    Image bmap;
    SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0);
    data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap)))
    {
        bmap = (Image)data.GetData(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
        ptb1.Image = bmap;
        ClosePreviewWindow();
        string _path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        _path += "E:\\DO AN TN\\QLyGiuXe\\QLyGiuXe\\bin\\Debug\\HinhAnhXeTmp" + 
        DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".bmp";
        _path.Replace("-", "_").Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "_");

        bmap.Save(_path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        //}
     }
 }
```

Comment: Maximum test but not been

Comment: thank you, I will do, hope you help me, because I should not have novice experience

Answer (score 0):

you are appending absolute path to Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

you may also want to try using something more acceptable for the timestamp

this seems to work:

```
string _path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
_path += "\\DO AN TN\\QLyGiuXe\\QLyGiuXe\\bin\\Debug\\HinhAnhXeTmp" +
DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".bmp";
_path.Replace("-", "_").Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "_");
```

Comment: Maximum test but not been

Comment: teamview you have not,

Comment: Can you more detailed instructions, I do not understand @Alex M

Comment: try replacing the four lines in your program with the code I wrote in this answer. do you get a different error message?

Comment: teamviewr you have not, why not milk directly lun on my computer, I was a student should not have much experience with c #